# Question about what it means to converge in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

so, we define a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ converging in probability to a random variable $X$ to be that $P(|X-X_n|> \epsilon)=0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now, consider the constant sequence of random variables $X_n$ which are the outcome of a coinflip but tails maps to 0 and heads map to 1. Now let $X$ be the same situation but flipping a different coin (ie independent).

Does $X_n$ converge to $X$ in probability? if it does, why? It seems like from the defintion above that there is a 1/2 chance of $X$ and $X_n$ differing by 1. Am I using these definitions right?

Comment: You want $n\to\infty$, not $\epsilon\to0$ in your definition....

Comment: ahh, you're right. But otherwise does my example work?

Answer (score 3):

No. In the definition, we want "For every $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_n P(|X-X_n|>\epsilon)=0.$"

Let $\epsilon=1/2$. Then in your example, with probability 1/2, $X_n=1$ for all $n$, and with probability 1/2, $X_n=0$ for all $n$. Further, $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=1/2$ and $X$ is independent of $X_n$ for each $n$, so $P(X=1\cap X_n=0)=P(X=1)P(X_n=0)=1/4.$ Note $\{X=1\}\cap \{X_n=0\}\subset \{|X_n-X|>1/2\}$, so $P(|X-X_n|>1/2)\ge 1/4$ for each $n$, and hence $\lim_n P(|X-X_n|>1/2)\neq0$.